# two project directory in ssame server, apache. how can i differentiate

Tags: apache

now the situation is like am trying to  view the www.b.com

it is going to document root of a.com

how can i change it as both a and b should work.?
can i use alias.?

like checking id there is bb in request  go to document root of bb or else
go to document root of aa.

What can i do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run Apache with 2 `VirtualHost` elements - one for a.com and one for b.com.

Each can point to it's own `DocumentRoot`

The config will be something like

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "C:\My Sites\Site1"
   ServerName a.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "C:\My Sites\Site2"
   ServerName b.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Read more at http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost